# RepeatingSpriteBackground on MenuScene

Tags: android, background, andengine, repeat

I have started using Andengine, and after following some tutorials I'm starting to develope for myself.
Right now I have a a BaseGameActivity where I call one splashScene(working fine) and after that my MenuScene.
If i set a simple background (just color) it loads fine (all menu text are displayed), but when i try to set a repeating sprite as background, a black screen appears (no error show in logcat)
I'm using the example code for the background

```
super(BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().mCamera);
activity = BaseActivity.getSharedInstance();
RepeatingSpriteBackground mGrassBackground = new RepeatingSpriteBackground(mCamera.getWidth(), mCamera.getHeight(), activity.getTextureManager(), AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(activity.getAssets(), "images/menu/background.png"), activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
this.setBackground(mGrassBackground);
```

I placed this code in the MenuScene constructor.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just discover my problem.
The code was right the problem was in the image format, it has to be a power of two (it says that clearly in the source code comments)

Next time I will try to read carefully before asking